# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed" for the bean with the "view" scope

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, illegalstateexception, mojarra, joinfaces

Currently we are migrating the Jakarta Faces application from WildFly to Spring Boot v.3.1.1 using JoinFaces v.5.1.1. The version of PrimeFaces is 12.0.0. The implementation of Jakarta Faces is Mojarra v.4.0.2. I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed" during the invocation of the code `filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);` in the doFilter() method of a filter. I've found a "problematic" bean which has the scope org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope(scopeName = "view"). If I change the scope to any other than "view" (e.g. to "request" scope) the problem disappears. But I'm not sure that this is a valid way to fix the issue. Are there any ideas how I can move forward with the resolution of this problem?

Comment: So the page being opened doesn't have any `<h:form>` component?

Comment: Actually the page being opened does have <h:form> component.

Comment: To be more specific inside <h:form> we have <p:commandButton> to log-out user: <h:form><p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{userBean.logout}" /></h:form>. And logout() method of the UserBean class calls FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession(). So the issue described above appears when the logout button is clicked.

Comment: So you aren't sending a redirect after logout?

Comment: After logout we're sending redirect to login page: return "/login?faces-redirect=true";